# What is the point of using #if MACROVALUE #endif inside a code?

Tags: c++, qt

Encountered this in a code and not sure what the point is.

```
#if !NO_HW
//code
#endif
saveSettingsFile();
}
```

I've never seen #if #endif inside a (SLOT) function like that, only traditional `#ifndef #define #endif` inside headerfile declarations. I dug online and found that `#if(condition) ..code.. #endif` the code inbetween is executed when condition is true, that I can understand, but we `#define NO_HW 0` earlier in the code, which means whenever this SLOT function is called it will always execute the code between `#if ... #endif` since !NO_HW will always return a nonzero value. NO_HW is a defined macro_name with a value  thus it's not like we can change it somewhere later in our code, so I don't understand the need of having #if !NO_HW ... #endif in our code in the first place besides for if the user wants to be able to later disable this section of the code if a specific hardware was to be removed (for our application, I believe this #define described a hardware PXIe). (I'm taking over someone else's code which is currently functional.)

Do you think this is the point of the code? To be enable/disable a section
of code depending on if a certain hardware component is present which is done in code by changing what `#define NO_HW 0` is set to?

```
//DECLARATIONS
#define NO_HW 0

//later, inside a SLOT function
void MainWindow::setOptions(void)
{
#if !NO_HW //this is the line I don't understand

// lot of regular inline if(statment) inlineAction; lines follow
// ...  
#endif

saveSettingsFile();
}
```

Comment: The normal `if` does refer to what you state _he code inbetween is executed when condition is true_, the `#if`will be **compiled** is condition is true.

Comment: I understand, but why would somebody use the condition for the `#if` statement to be a global variable? Just to be able to turn that section of code on and off?

Comment: Exactly. like `#if _DEBUG printf("This is an extra debug message"); #endif`

Comment: Ah got it, welp, not sure how to mark the question as answered now but thank you.

Comment: Why would it act differently outside of a header file?

Comment: @DaveNewton I am not a proficient coder, so I accepted that that is how we define header files so that we can later `#include "name.h"` inside the .c or .cpp file. That's a bit different than only enabling a section of code using `#if COND ... #endif`. I wasn't sure if you are asking to question why I was confused or for clarification.

Comment: Pre-processor directives don't "define a header file", they're used anywhere (header or not) to affect compile-time behavior, in whatever way the developer wishes.

Comment: @DaveNewton So you are just saying that the main point is that pre-processor directives are pre-compiled by the processor before the actual program executes, basically the definition of pre-processor directives. Correct? I appreciate your comment of reminding me to be mindful that while header files are just one application, the main point lies elsewhere, but you could have done it in a bit more educational way, as I said, I am learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your guess is correct. This is used a lot in C/C++, for instance to distinguish between different operating systems, and to enable/disable configurations which don't ever change at runtime.

This is all done by the preprocessor before the code is compiled. `gcc -E test.cpp` to run only the preprocessor stage

```
// test.cpp 
#include <iostream>
#define PRINT_A

int main(){
        #ifdef PRINT_A
                std::cout << "section a" << std::endl;
        #endif

        #ifdef PRINT_B
                std::cout << "section b" << std::endl;
        #endif

        return 0;
}
```

## output of gcc -E test.cpp

```
int main(){
  std::cout << "section a" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

## output of gcc -D PRINT_B -E test.cpp

```
int main(){
  std::cout << "section a" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "section b" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessor macros can be use to enable/disable part of code such as:

```
#if _DEBUG 
    printf("This is an extra debug message"); 
#endif

#define ROUNDING 0
float val = 1.2f;
#if ROUNDING 
    int a = (val + 0.5f); // If ROUNDING was 1, the val could have been rounded instead of floor.
#else 
    int a = val; 
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my intuition was right (as confirmed in comments with user @Vuwox). Using a global variable for the condition inside a `#if CONDITION ...code #endif` inside a function is to enable/disable that section of code by simply changing the value of the macro which is much easier done by the use of a macro variable which is defined on top of a code.